# Laravel "@include" directive using with a filter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Below code is Laravel blade for render some data from server.

If I use below code to another page with @include directive why render only Auth user's data in the Referenced Child Page, then how can I make filtering?

**samples/table.blade.php**

```
<div style="overflow-x: auto; display:flex;">
<table class="table table-responsive" id="jobs-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Brukernavn</th>
            <th>Kundenavn</th>
            <th>Sted</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Note</th>
            <th>Starttid</th>
            <th colspan="3">Handling</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($jobs as $job)
        <tr>
            <td>{!! $job->user_name !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $job->customer_name !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $job->job_place !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $job->job_type !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $job->note_1 !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $job->created_at !!}</td>
            <td>
                {!! Form::open(['route' => ['jobs.destroy', $job->id], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
                <div class='btn-group'>
                    <a href="{!! route('jobs.show', [$job->id]) !!}" class='btn btn-info btn-xs'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></a>
                    @can('stop', $job)
                    <a href="{!! route('jobs.edit', [$job->id]) !!}" class='btn btn-warning btn-xs'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>                            
                    {!! Form::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs', 'onclick' => "return confirm('Are you sure to Stop?')"]) !!}
                    @endcan
                </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
{{ $jobs->links() }}
```

**Referenced child pages**

```
<div style="overflow-x: auto;">
<table class="table table-responsive" id="jobs-table">
    @include('samples.table')
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit better what you want? Also post your controller method that loads this view

Comment: @ljubadr, My goal is only render with if the value is (deleted_at == null) from upper parents blade. Thanks.

Comment: You should do the filtering in controller or model, and pass that data into the view. That's why I said to add controller method that calls this view. If you are really set to do that in the view, you should look into [collections filter() method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-filter)

Comment: Also, in parent view you have `<table>` and then you have `<table>` in your `@include` again. You should remove `<table>` from parent view